# Lucene ignore keywords in search term

Tags: lucene

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure out how to get Lucene to ignore  the AND, OR, and NOT keywords - the query parser throws a parse error when it gets one.  I have a query builder class that splits the search term so that it searches on the words themselves as well as on n-grams in the word.  I'm using Lucene in Java.

So in a search for, say, "ANDERSON COOPER" the query string looks like:

```
name: (ANDERSON COOPER "ANDERSON COOPER")^5 gram4: ( ANDE NDER DERS ERSO RSON 
SONC ONCO NCOO COOP OOPE OPER)
```

the query parser throws an error when it gets those ANDs.  Ideally, I'd like the parser to just ignore AND, OR, NOT altogether, and I'll use the &&, ||, and ! equivalents if I need them - do I have to modify the code in the QueryParser class itself to get this?  Or is there an easier way?   I could also just insert an escape character for these cases if that is the best way to do it, but adding `\` before the word AND doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the `AND` in quotes like this: `"AND"`.  Is that easy?  A regex could probably do that easily if you know exactly what your queries look like.

The parser shouldn't have a problem with it, and the PhraseQuery will be rewritten as a term query, so it will be a small constant-time performance difference big-oh `O(1)`.

The regex could probably look like this:

```
\b(AND|OR|NOT)\b
```

Which would be replaced with

```
"$1"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! I had tried wrapping the name in quotes, but each of the n-grams need to be in quotes as well.   About as easy a solution as a I could have hoped for.